# Jumping text on android native app with phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, html, css, cordova

I'm building an app for Android with Phonegap and there is a small problem. When i navigate through the pages, all the text on the page moves up and down in about 2 seconds (movement is a couple of pixels, not much but very annoying). I also get the problem while scrolling through (when I release my fingers from the screen).

I use iScroll and jQuery (not jQuery mobile) for my app.

I hope someone can help me with the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .css file :

```
body 
{
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please follow this link : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024.... Hope it will help.